Consuming an iterable/list/generator of dynamically loaded pytest fixtures
I'm trying to create a dynamic fixture loader for pytest that does some work after the value is yielded to the test. In the beginning, I didn't need to do anything that complicated, so I just returned the fixture once it was ready:
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

from pytest import CaptureFixture
import pytest

from .tests import testutils

FIXTURES_ROOT = Path(__file__).parent / "fixtures"
INBOX = Path(__file__).parent / "inbox"
CONVERTED = Path(__file__).parent / "converted"


class TestItem:

    converted_dir: Path

    def __init__(self, inbox_dir: Path):
        self.inbox_dir = inbox_dir
        self.converted_dir = CONVERTED / inbox_dir.name

def load_test_fixture(
    name: str,
    *,
    exclusive: bool = False,
    override_name: str | None = None,
    match_filter: str | None = None,
    cleanup_inbox: bool = False,
):
    src = FIXTURES_ROOT / name
    if not src.exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError(
            f"Fixture {name} not found. Does it exist in {FIXTURES_ROOT}?"
        )
    dst = INBOX / (override_name or name)
    dst.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for f in src.glob("**/*"):
        dst_f = dst / f.relative_to(src)
        if f.is_file() and not dst_f.exists():
            dst_f.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            shutil.copy(f, dst_f)

    # if any files in dst are not in src, delete them
    for f in dst.glob("**/*"):
        src_f = src / f.relative_to(dst)
        if f.is_file() and not src_f.exists():
            f.unlink()

    if exclusive or match_filter is not None:
        testutils.set_match_filter(match_filter or name)

    converted_dir = CONVERTED / (override_name or name)
    shutil.rmtree(converted_dir, ignore_errors=True)

    return TestItem(dst)

This works well - the fixture loads dynamically, and I can create a bunch of one-liner fixtures out of it:

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def basic_fixture():
    return load_test_fixture("basic_fixture", exclusive=True)

def test_converted_dir_exists(
    basic_fixture: TestItem, capfd: CaptureFixture[str]
):
    assert basic_fixture.converted_dir.exists()

I've also gone and greated a multi-fixture loader that returns an array of fixtures:
def load_test_fixtures(
    *names: str,
    exclusive: bool = False,
    override_names: list[str] | None = None,
    match_filter: str | None = None,
):
    if exclusive:
        match_filter = match_filter or rf"^({'|'.join(override_names or names)})"

    return [
        load_test_fixture(name, override_name=override, match_filter=match_filter)
        for (name, override) in zip(names, override_names or names)
    ]

But now I want to have the loader act more like a fixture, where it can yield the item and then clean up after itself. This works fine for the single loader:
def load_test_fixture(
    name: str,
    *,
    exclusive: bool = False,
    override_name: str | None = None,
    match_filter: str | None = None,
    cleanup_inbox: bool = False,
):
    # ...
    # instead of returning, yield the item

    yield TestItem(dst)

    if cleanup_inbox:
        shutil.rmtree(dst, ignore_errors=True)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def basic_fixture():
    yield from load_test_fixture("basic_fixture", exclusive=True)

But I can't get it to work with the multiloader, because it returns either a generator of generators, or a list of generators. I've tried converting these both to @pytest.fixtures as well, but can't seem to get the list version to yield its items and properly wait to clean up after the test completes, and as fixtures, I'd have the added problem of dealing with passing args as indirect or params (ew).
def load_test_fixtures(
    *names: str,
    exclusive: bool = False,
    override_names: list[str] | None = None,
    match_filter: str | None = None,
):
    if exclusive:
        match_filter = match_filter or rf"^({'|'.join(override_names or names)})"

    yield from (
        load_test_fixture(name, match_filter=match_filter, override_name=override)
        for name, override in zip(names, override_names or names)
    )
    # tried all combinations of list, tuple, and yield here, as well as

    # yield (next(load_test_fixture(name, match_filter=match_filter, override_name=override))
    #    for name, override in zip(names, override_names or names)

I even tried this, which sort of works, but doesn't wait for the end of the test to run the finalizer:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def multi_fixtures():
    fixtures = []
    for f in [
        "basic_fixture",
        "fancy_fixture",
        "tasty_fixture",
        "smart_fixture",
    ]:
        fixtures.extend(
            load_test_fixture(f, match_filter=match_filter, cleanup_inbox=True)
        )
    yield fixtures

(If I pass cleanup_inbox=True here, it deletes the files before the test runs).

Alright, it's kinda gross because it requires passing the request param from the fixture, but ended up doing this to work around it. If there's a more elegant way, I'd love to find out.
def rm_from_inbox(*names: str):
    for name in names:
        inbox = INBOX / name
        shutil.rmtree(inbox, ignore_errors=True)
        testutils.print(f"Cleaning up {inbox}")

# Updated `load_test_fixture` to also call `rm_from_inbox`:
# ...
# if cleanup_inbox:
#     rm_from_inbox(name)

def load_test_fixtures(
    *names: str,
    exclusive: bool = False,
    override_names: list[str] | None = None,
    match_filter: str | None = None,
    cleanup_inbox: bool = False,
    request: pytest.FixtureRequest | None = None,
):
    if exclusive:
        match_filter = match_filter or rf"^({'|'.join(override_names or names)})"

    fixtures: list[TestItem] = []
    for name, override in zip(names, override_names or names):
        fixtures.extend(
            load_test_fixture(name, match_filter=match_filter, override_name=override)
        )

    if cleanup_inbox:
        if not request:
            raise ValueError(
                "cleanup_inbox requires `request` to be a pytest.FixtureRequest"
            )
        request.addfinalizer(lambda: rm_from_inbox(*names))

    return fixtures

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def all_hardy_boys(request: pytest.FixtureRequest):
    yield load_test_fixtures(
        "basic_fixture",
        "fancy_fixture",
        "tasty_fixture",
        "smart_fixture",
        exclusive=True,
        request=request,
        cleanup_inbox=True,
    )


